# Expected `()`, found `Result<ServiceResponse<B>, _>` using middleware in actix_web trying to return Ok

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm trying to accomplish a very simple task here. I don't understand why it has become so complex. I'm attempting to modify headers before they reach the service and return a failure if a certain condition is not met.

Here is my middleware file:

```
use std::future::{ready, Ready};

use actix_http::header::{HeaderValue, HeaderName};
use actix_web::{
    dev::{self, Service, ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse, Transform},
    Error,http::Method
};
use futures_util::future::LocalBoxFuture;
//use crate::constants;

pub struct Heartbeat;

impl<S, B> Transform<S, ServiceRequest> for Heartbeat
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = HeartMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ready(Ok(HeartMiddleware { service }))
    }
}

pub struct HeartMiddleware<S> {
    service: S,
}


impl<S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for HeartMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = LocalBoxFuture<'static, Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

    dev::forward_ready!(service);

    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        

        let fut = self.service.call(req);
        
        

        Box::pin(async move {
            
            let mut res = fut.await?;
            let headers = res.headers_mut();
            headers.insert(
                 HeaderName::from_static("Content-Type"), HeaderValue::from_static("text/plain")
             );
            
            if (Method::POST == req.method() || 
                 Method::GET  == req.method()  ||
                 Method::HEAD == req.method()) && req.path() == "/ping" {
                 Ok(res)
            }
             
            Err(actix_web::error::ErrorImATeapot("TeaPot"))
        })
    }
}
```

and the main file :

```
use actix_web::{get,web,http,Result,App,HttpServer,HttpRequest, Responder, HttpResponse};
use serde::{Deserialize,Serialize};
use actix_cors::Cors;

mod heartbeat;

static PORT :u16 = 9091;

#[get("/")]
async fn index()->impl Responder {
    
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("template")
}

 

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Response {
    pub message: String,
}

async fn not_found() ->Result<HttpResponse> {
    let response = Response {
        message: "Resource not found".to_string(),
    };
    Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().json(response))
}


#[actix_web::main]
async fn main()-> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "debug");
    env_logger::init();
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new()
    .wrap(
        Cors::default()
            .allowed_origin("http://*") // Allow all http origins
            .allowed_origin("https://*") // Allow all https origins
            .allowed_methods(vec!["GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS"])
            .allowed_headers(vec![http::header::AUTHORIZATION,http::header::CONTENT_TYPE,
                http::header::ACCEPT,http::header::LINK])
            .allowed_header("X-CSRF-TOKEN")
            .supports_credentials()
            .max_age(300)
    )
    .wrap(heartbeat::Heartbeat)
    .service(index)
    .service(web::resource("/ping"))
    .default_service(web::route().to(not_found)))
    .bind(("127.0.0.1",PORT))?
    .run()
    .await        
}
```

When I compile it, I'm getting:

```
cargo build
   Compiling broker-service v0.1.0 (C:\dev\my\rust\workspace\broker-service)
warning: unused import: `HttpRequest`
 --> src\main.rs:1:52
  |
1 | use actix_web::{get,web,http,Result,App,HttpServer,HttpRequest, Responder, HttpResponse};
  |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: unused import: `Deserialize`
 --> src\main.rs:2:13
  |
2 | use serde::{Deserialize,Serialize};
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\heartbeat.rs:65:18
   |
62 | /             if (Method::POST == req.method() ||
63 | |                  Method::GET  == req.method()  ||
64 | |                  Method::HEAD == req.method()) && req.path() == "/ping" {
65 | |                  Ok(res)
   | |                  ^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `Result<ServiceResponse<B>, _>`
66 | |             }
   | |_____________- expected this to be `()`
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                   found enum `Result<ServiceResponse<B>, _>`
note: return type inferred to be `()` here
  --> src\heartbeat.rs:56:27
   |
56 |             let mut res = fut.await?;
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
warning: `broker-service` (bin "broker-service") generated 2 warnings
error: could not compile `broker-service` (bin "broker-service") due to previous error; 2 warnings emitted
```

### Update

After updating the solution suggested, I am still getting an error:

```
use std::future::{ready, Ready};

use actix_http::header::{HeaderValue, HeaderName};
use actix_web::{
    dev::{self, Service, ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse, Transform},
    Error,http::Method
};
use futures_util::future::LocalBoxFuture;
//use crate::constants;

pub struct Heartbeat;

impl<S, B> Transform<S, ServiceRequest> for Heartbeat
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = HeartMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ready(Ok(HeartMiddleware { service }))
    }
}

pub struct HeartMiddleware<S> {
    service: S,
}


impl<S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for HeartMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = LocalBoxFuture<'static, Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

    dev::forward_ready!(service);

    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        

        let fut = self.service.call(req);
        
        

        Box::pin(async move {
            
            let mut res = fut.await?;
            let headers = res.headers_mut();
            headers.insert(
                 HeaderName::from_static("Content-Type"), HeaderValue::from_static("text/plain")
             );
            
            if (Method::POST == req.method() || 
                 Method::GET  == req.method()  ||
                 Method::HEAD == req.method()) && req.path() == "/ping" {
                 return Ok(res)
            }
             
            Err(actix_web::error::ErrorImATeapot("TeaPot"))
        })
    }
}
```

```
cargo build
   Compiling broker-service v0.1.0 (C:\dev\my\rust\workspace\broker-service)
warning: unused import: `HttpRequest`
 --> src\main.rs:1:52
  |
1 | use actix_web::{get,web,http,Result,App,HttpServer,HttpRequest, Responder, HttpResponse};
  |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: unused import: `Deserialize`
 --> src\main.rs:2:13
  |
2 | use serde::{Deserialize,Serialize};
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `req`
  --> src\heartbeat.rs:54:18
   |
47 |       fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
   |                      --- move occurs because `req` has type `ServiceRequest`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
50 |           let fut = self.service.call(req);
   |                                       --- value moved here
...
54 |           Box::pin(async move {
   |  __________________^
55 | |
56 | |             let mut res = fut.await?;
57 | |             let headers = res.headers_mut();
...  |
62 | |             if (Method::POST == req.method() ||
   | |                                 --- use occurs due to use in generator
...  |
68 | |             Err(actix_web::error::ErrorImATeapot("TeaPot"))
69 | |         })
   | |_________^ value used here after move

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
warning: `broker-service` (bin "broker-service") generated 2 warnings
error: could not compile `broker-service` (bin "broker-service") due to previous error; 2 warnings emitted
```

Comment: The ```return type inferred to be `()` here``` is wrong and misleading. You can file an issue.

Comment: file issue where ?

Comment: In the Rust repository. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/new?assignees=&labels=A-diagnostics%2CT-compiler&projects=&template=diagnostics.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` is a statement, not an expression. You're basically telling the compiler "execute this `if` and throw away the result, then return `Err`". The result must be of type `()`.

You want an explicit `return`:

```rust
Box::pin(async move {
    let mut res = fut.await?;
    let headers = res.headers_mut();
    headers.insert(
        HeaderName::from_static("Content-Type"),
        HeaderValue::from_static("text/plain"),
    );

    if (Method::POST == req.method()
        || Method::GET == req.method()
        || Method::HEAD == req.method())
        && req.path() == "/ping"
    {
        return Ok(res);
    }

    Err(actix_web::error::ErrorImATeapot("TeaPot"))
})
```

Or add an `else`, to make the whole thing an expression:

```rust
Box::pin(async move {
    let mut res = fut.await?;
    let headers = res.headers_mut();
    headers.insert(
        HeaderName::from_static("Content-Type"),
        HeaderValue::from_static("text/plain"),
    );

    if (Method::POST == req.method()
        || Method::GET == req.method()
        || Method::HEAD == req.method())
        && req.path() == "/ping"
    {
        Ok(res)
    } else {
        Err(actix_web::error::ErrorImATeapot("TeaPot"))
    }
})
```

Comment: did you try it ?  it dosnt work gives me both gives me :
  Box::pin(async move {
   |  __________________^
55 | |
56 | |             let mut res = fut.await?;
57 | |             let headers = res.headers_mut();
...  |
62 | |             if (Method::POST == req.method() ||
   | |                                 --- use occurs due to use in generator
...  |
68 | |             Err(actix_web::error::ErrorImATeapot("TeaPot"))
69 | |         })
   | |_________^ value used here after move

Comment: @user63898 I didn't, but this looks like a different, unrelated error.

Comment: this is error im getting after what you suggest ( i did it before )

Comment: @user63898 I understand, but this is not related. What I said is still correct, and `return` (or `else`) is the correct way to write this code. Now we have another, different error that we need to solve.

Comment: ok any idea what is the error ?

Comment: @user63898 It is hard to read in a comment, so I don't know.

Comment: i updated the main questions